# How to convert Final String [name] to a double in flutter?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

I am trying to make a calculator but I don't know how to convert a string to a double using the double.parse(*name*) method? I am reading *name* from a textfield and passing it to the next page but it takes the form of final String *name* so it's not static.

The double.parse() requires a static variable but I don't know how to pass on a static variable between pages. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please provide some code to describe your problem in order to get help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int.parse()` or `double.parse()`

Do let me know if you want some other answer

```
var integerNumber = int.parse('103455');//Converts string to integer
print(integerNumber); //Output: 103455

var doubleNumber = double.parse('103.455');//Converts string to double
print(doubleNumber); //Output: 103.455
```

This may help you

Comment: hi hardik, thanks for your help but I don't think this will work for me. I am reading the textfield controller which will give me a "final string x" so the x could be anything from 0 to 1000000. I tried double.parse(x) before but it didn't work.

Comment: It would be better if you add some code so that i'll able to understand what you need exactly.